# Node.js cannot find module that is globally installed on MacOS

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, selenium-webdriver

I have installed `selenium-webdriver` globally using `nmp install -g`.
I have also made sure that path to the global `node_modules` is present in the NODE_PATH environment variable.
However when I try to execute a simple .js script, node fails to find the nodule.
I feel I'm missing something rather simple here, but can't figure out what.

```
ip-192-168-4-31:end2endtests xxxxx$ npm ls -g|grep "selenium.*" 
└─┬ selenium-webdriver@4.0.0-alpha.1
ip-192-168-4-31:end2endtests xxxxx$ echo $NODE_PATH
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
ip-192-168-4-31:end2endtests xxxxx$ node tests.js
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'selenium-webdriver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/xxxxx/Documents/end2endtests/helpers.js:1:79)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

Comment: My understanding of node_modules is that the scope for the project does not extend past the project itself. I have not come across installing the selenium-webdriver globally but I would suggest installing it in the project and seeing if that works.

Comment: well, installing locally works. And I understand that this might be the best option to make sure all packages are in the project repo. However, I was wondering, what's use of global node_modules if node installs, but doesn't see them? How is that supposed to work?

Comment: I believe they are command line modules. Think tools that build and run your javascript. Often times you will install things both locally and globally to interact with the project in different ways. Mostly global module looks for the local module, I haven't come across the opposite yet. Example, mocha.js is used at the command line to run tests with 'mocha test.js', and that's the generally use of installing things globally.